# Changing value of const int using using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I wrote a C program in gcc and it's giving me very unexpected output. The code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int x=10;
    int *p=&x;
    *p=11;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    printf("%d",x);

    printf("\n%u\n",p);
    printf("%u", &x);
    }
```

Here output is:

11

10

37814068

37814068

Why do p and &x give the same address(37814068) but different values(5,10)??

Comment: Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall`), and this code won't compile cleanly.  Use `-Werror` to prevent it compiling at all.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a `const` variable (directly or through a pointer) invokes undefined behavior. You may not get the same result in another machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the C Standard mofiying a constant is an undefined behaviour. It means that anything could happen it depends on the machine you're running and the compiler your using. In some cases constants are puted on read-only memory and modifying it's value will cause the program to crash.

Exemple of the error generated by the GCC compiler:

```
error: assignment of read-only location '* p'
  *p = 11;
     ^
```