# Behaviour of const int pointer - C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have a C program

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(const int* p)
{
  int j;
  p = &j;
  j = 10;
  printf("Inside function *p = %d\n",*p);
  *p = 5;
  printf("Inside function *p = %d\n",*p);
  j = 7;
  printf("Inside function *p = %d\n",*p);
}

int main()
{
  int i = 20, *q = &i;
  f(q);
}
```

Compilation of the program gives the error

> Assignment of the read only location *p

at the line `*p = 5;`

Why is that the assignment `j = 10;` is valid and `*p = 5;` is an error.

Comment: You declared `p` to be a `const int *p`. The `const` means you don't intend to change the value of `*p`. But you did, so got the error. `j` is declared as `int j`. It's not `const`, so you can change it.

Comment: @mbratch This could be the point, but djhaskin explains more clearly.

Comment: [Changing value of const int using using pointer duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929551/changing-value-of-const-int-using-using-pointer?rq=1), [Const variable changed with pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371892/const-variable-changed-with-pointer-in-c), [Confusion regarding modification of const variable using pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372713/confusion-regarding-modification-of-const-variable-using-pointers?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const int *p` means that you can't modify the integer that `p` is pointing to using `p`, as in `*p = 5;`. The integer it points to may not be a `const int`, which is why `j = 10` works. This prevents coders from modifying integer being pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

const int* p mean you can not change the content in the address of p

which is you can not chanage *p

Comment: Noob question: why is `p = &j` allowed then?

Comment: @naomik change function definition to void f(const* int* p), you will get the error for that too, const * int p mean you can not change where p point to

Answer (score 0):

**const int** mean , its value `remain same` until program ends so you can not change its value.